# How to create a cartogram-heatmap (non-US)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geofacet

I want to create a map like:

[image]

*edit: this screenshot is from Claus Wilkes book [Fundamentals of Data Visualization](https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/)*

But as I'm living in Switzerland, I haven't found a package where I can use this out of the box. Also I haven't found something for Germany or Austria.

Then I discovered the package [geofacet](https://digital.ebp.ch/2021/03/02/tilemaps-in-r/), which covers many countries (even smaller ones like CH) and allows to create a grid like:

[image]

After some tweeking arround a while, I managed to get to this point:

[image]

There are still some details, which I need to fix, but I'm facing two problems, that I don't know how to solve:

1. How can I plot rounded squares (like in the initial picture)?
2. How can I use the state/canton name in the middle of the plot, like a watermark? I my last attempt, I removed the facet label and used an annotation, but couldn't use the state values from the column.

I would appreciate any help. Also if there is anyone out there who has had the same problem in the past and found an easier solution than mine.

### MWE

This is the code for the last plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(geofacet)

test = data.frame("state"=c("ZH", "AG", "TI", "BS"), value=c(1,2,3,4))

ggplot(data=test, aes(fill=value)) +
  geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=1, xmax=2, ymin=1, ymax=2), color="black", alpha=0.5) +
  annotate("text", x=1.5, y=1.5, label= "state") +
  facet_geo(~state, grid="ch_cantons_grid2") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 5),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

For rounded square, see [hrbrmstr/statebins](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/statebins)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(geofacet)
library(dplyr)
test = data.frame(state=c("ZH", "AG", "TI", "BS"), value=c(1,2,3,4))

# devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/statebins")

grid_geo <- geofacet::ch_cantons_grid2$code

test$state <- factor(test$state, levels = grid_geo)

test <- dplyr::right_join(test, dplyr::tibble(grid_geo), by = c('state' = 'grid_geo'))

ggplot(data=test ) +
    statebins:::geom_rrect(data=test, mapping=aes(xmin=1, xmax=2, ymin=1, ymax=2), 
                           fill = 'white', 
                           color="black", alpha=0.5) +
    statebins:::geom_rrect(data=test %>% 
                               dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)),
                                             mapping=aes(xmin=1, xmax=2, ymin=1, ymax=2, fill =  value), 
              color="black", alpha=0.5) +
    geom_text(data=test, aes(x = 1.5, y = 1.5, label = state)) +
    # annotate("text", x=1.5, y=1.5, label= state) +
    facet_geo(~state, grid="ch_cantons_grid2") +
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          strip.placement = "bottom",
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 5),
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text.x = element_blank(), 
          line = element_blank())
```

[image]

Here is another code to mimick the visual that you show.

```r
ggplot(data=test) +
    statebins:::geom_rrect(data=test, mapping=aes(xmin=1, xmax=2, ymin=1, ymax=2), 
                           fill = '#d0e1e1', 
                           color=NA, alpha=0.7) +
    statebins:::geom_rrect(data=test %>% 
                               dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)),
                                             mapping=aes(xmin=1, xmax=2, ymin=1, ymax=2, fill =  value), 
              color=NA, alpha=1) +
    geom_text(data=test, aes(x = 1.5, y = 1.5, label = state)) +
    # annotate("text", x=1.5, y=1.5, label= state) +
    facet_geo(~state, grid="ch_cantons_grid2") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "#dccbd7", high = '#564364', name = "Label value") +
    theme_minimal() + 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top")) +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.95), 
          legend.direction="horizontal") +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          strip.placement = "bottom",
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 5),
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text.x = element_blank(), 
          line = element_blank())
```

[image]

You can change `guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))` by `guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title.position = "top"))` to have continuous color scale.

[image]